# An app that made with sdk 4.0.1 doesn't install on device with os 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I made an app with ios sdk 4.0.1 but now i want to install it from xcode on ipod touch with os 4.2 but says

> No provisioned iPhone OS device is
>   connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think above method will not resolve the problem.

**Follow these steps:**

1) Go into Project -> Project Edit Settings

2) Set Base Sdk iOS4.2

3) Set MacOS Deployment Target : MAC OSX 10.5

4) iOS Deployment Target: iOS4.0

Thats it

Cheers,

Tariq

Comment: in "Edit project Setting" doesn't exist iOS 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Open up organizer, with your device plugged in, and select it in the list on the left. Then once selected, click "Use for Development." This should fix you right up.

Answer (score 1):

If the above doesn't work (and it almost certainly should help), you might try disconnecting and reconnecting your device and or rebooting your device and/or mac.

Side note - it's good practice to always compile against the latest SDK (currently 4.2) and set your build Deployment Target to the minimum version of the OS you wish to support.